# Tails with espect to a Random Variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\pi$ be the law of a standard random variable and let $f$ be a measurable function. For a fixed $p$, how is $\pi(f>p)$ computed?

Is this as simple as $A:=\{x : f(x)>p\}$ and
$$\pi(f>p) = \int_{A}\pi(dx)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{A} e^{-x^2/2} dx.$$

I'm not sure if $f$ plays any other role in the integral.

Comment: If $f\sin \mathcal N(0,1)$ yes. "Is this as simple as..." good luck anyway to compute $\pi\{f>p\}$ for an unspecified $p$...

Comment: You mean if $f \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$? Here I'm considering an arbitrary function $f$.

Comment: Therefore, your formula is wrong...

Comment: Hmm. How's it written out for general $f$? Is it with respect to the random variable $f(X)$, where $X$ is a standard normal?